# Programmatically creating functions in c++

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose we have a code that contains 1000 copies of function with the following form:

```cpp
function myname_[X](args){
    struct somevariable_[X];
    //others
}
```

where [X] is a sequence say 0001, 0002 etc.

I intend to make it cleaner by programmatically generating the function and variable names instead. How can we do this in c++?

Comment: Why do you need 1000 functions? What is different between each of these functions? Is the code different or is it just the data that the code acts on that's different? If it's the later, then you only need one function.

Comment: C++ does not allow you to create functions at runtime. However, there might be a different solution to your problem. You'll have to provide more details of the problem you are trying to solve though.

Comment: @RSahu "*C++ does not allow you to create functions at runtime*" - true, but it is fairly trivial to dynamically allocate a block of memory with executable rights, copy prepared machine instructions into that memory, and then use it like any other function. Plenty of frameworks use this technique for making executable thunks dynamically at runtime, for instance.

Comment: With what you have shown here, you only need one function and you pass `somevariable` as an argument.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, is that what happens under the covers when you load a DLL?

Comment: Is it because the 3rd-party library takes a c-style callback with no `void*` user-provided argument?

Comment: @RSahu no, it is not.  I was referring more to frameworks like ATL, MFC, VCL, etc which use dynamic thunks to provide proxying of non-static class methods on a per-object basic for things like C-style callbacks, Win32 window message handlers, etc.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that is what I am doing but the 3rd party lib does not allow that, it wants a dedicated function for what ever argument you pass or else it will overwrite it.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin almost like what you mentioned.

Comment: @James Guana could you simply provide a 3D library function declaration which you need to use ? It seems like you simply need a functor which will collect result into a collection like vector or list.

Comment: This is likely an example of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead, why don't you give more details about your problem with the third party library instead of the solution you think you need?

Comment: libffi can create executable code at run-time (a concrete example of Remy Lebeau's comment), the closure part of the library is able to package sets of arguments in order to massage parameter sets needed by your function to a function signature required by a callback system. You provide the cclosure to the function taking the callback and use the code provided to libffi to unpack the saved data along with whatever arguments are taken in order to call your 'real' callback.

Comment: @VictorGubin You mean a struct? I have that, but the 3rd party callback has one to one relationship with a function, so if you called it again for a new data, it will ignore your previous data even if you have an increment for it. Sound illogical right?

Comment: Would it work if you wrap this function in a class and create a new object of this class anytime you want to use this 3rd party library? Must the function names be unique too?

Comment: I have not attempted that yet. But it might work

Comment: @JamesGuana Mentioning the XY problem is not a comment about your intelligence. Instead, Philip is pointing out that you appear to have started with a problem (using a 3rd party library) and you thought of a potential solution (generating functions programmatically) but there is likely a better solution to your original problem. If you edit your question to show the third party library that you are using and how you want to use it, then we can address that more direclty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use templates to generate a compile-time fixed number of c-style functions, each of which can pass a hard-coded argument to your C++ callback. You can use that hard-coded argument to associate the c-style callback with an object.

Here is a minimal working C++14 example that allows to associate a unique C++ `std::function` with each of the generated c-style callback. You can initialize that `std::function` with a lambda that captures whatever state you need in that particular callback:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

class Callbacks {
    static constexpr unsigned count = 1000;
    static Callbacks* instance;

    using CF = void(); // C-style callback type.
    using F = std::function<CF>; // C++ stateful callback type.

    F callbacks_[count];
    CF* c_style_callbacks_[count];

    template<unsigned Index>
    static void c_style_callback() {
        instance->callbacks_[Index]();
    }

    template<unsigned... Index>
    void make_c_style_callbacks(std::integer_sequence<unsigned, Index...>) {
        auto initializer_list = {(c_style_callbacks_[Index] = &c_style_callback<Index>)...};
        static_cast<void>(initializer_list);
    }

public:
    Callbacks() {
        make_c_style_callbacks(std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned, count>{});
        if(instance)
            throw; // One instance only please.
        instance = this;
    }

    Callbacks(Callbacks const&) = delete;
    Callbacks& operator=(Callbacks const&) = delete;

    ~Callbacks() noexcept {
        instance = 0;
    }

    CF* register_callback(F f) noexcept {
        // Linear search can be improved upon.
        auto condition = [](F const& f) { return !f; };
        auto index = std::find_if(std::begin(callbacks_), std::end(callbacks_), condition) - std::begin(callbacks_);
        if(index < count) {
            callbacks_[index] = std::move(f); // Assumes move-assignement is noexcept.
            return c_style_callbacks_[index];
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void unregister_callback(CF* cf) noexcept {
        // Linear search can be improved upon.
        auto index = std::find(std::begin(c_style_callbacks_), std::end(c_style_callbacks_), cf) - std::begin(c_style_callbacks_);
        if(index < count)
            callbacks_[index] = {};
        else
            throw; // cf has not been found. Programming error.
    }
};

Callbacks* Callbacks::instance = 0;

int main() {
    Callbacks c;
    unsigned n = 0;

    auto p0 = c.register_callback([m = n++]() { std::cout << m << '\n'; });
    auto p1 = c.register_callback([m = n++]() { std::cout << m << '\n'; });
    auto p2 = c.register_callback([m = n++]() { std::cout << m << '\n'; });

    p0(); // Outputs 0.
    p1(); // Outputs 1.
    p2(); // Outputs 2.

    c.unregister_callback(p2);
    c.unregister_callback(p1);
    c.unregister_callback(p0);
}
```

The solution requires using a bit of global state, which is `Callbacks::instance` here. An alternative would be to parametrize `c_style_callback` with a reference to an object with linkage (internal or external), which means a global, namespace-scoped or class static object.

If you are using C++11 you will need to use a backport of `std::integer_sequence` and `std::make_integer_sequence` which arrived in C++14 but don't actually require any C++14-specific features. Example `[m = n++]` named captures are also available since C++14, but that is just for demonstration.